# slow query on a partitioned table

Tags: partitioning, sql-server-2017

I have a huge table with 3B of rows containing around 6 months of data running on Microsoft SQL server 2017 (RTM), which is partitioned day by day on a date column (each day on a separate filegroup and each filegroup has 1 data file).

this table has an identity field which is bigint.

I have two indexes :
a clustered index on date and id
a non clustered index on date

I'm trying to run the following query :

```
select top 500000 * from table with(nolock) where id>@certain_id order by id
```

but the query is taking a lot of time. I tried to create an non clustered index on id field , but nothing changes!

the weird part I was able to run the same query with no issues and with fast response in the past. But due to some circumstances  I had to format the server and re-attach the database containing the partitioned table, and I'm now having this issue.

any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose this query worked fast when you had non-partitioned index on id but if your indexes are not aligned with partitions then partitioning has no sense at all. The question is - do you really need to run such query? Does id ordered the same way as date column?

Comment: most of the queries on the table don't include the id field , but I have to run this query for a specific task. what happen if I create a non-partitioned index on id ?

Comment: you will not be able to switch/truncate partitions for data loading/deletion

Comment: is there a way to run this query fast without creating the non partitioned index?

Comment: Does id ordered the same way as date column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question .In some cases old data are inserted to the table , so I assume id is not ordered the same way as date column.

Comment: Try to create partitioned index, your query will still need to scan it and sort data but it may work faster than scan the whole table. Then you may try to improve the performance reducing the amount of  data to sort selecting the first 500 000 ids from each partition. But let's get back to the first question - why do you need to run such strange query? And one more question - what is the purpose of partitioning in your case?

Comment: I have to sync this table with another table in another server, so I run this query to insert the data to the backup table. Normally I run this query every 1 minute so there will not be 500000 to select , but now I have around 15 days to copy to the backup table as my environment was offline for a certain time. I use partitioning to benefit from  data management features such as keep 6 months in the table and re-use the oldest partition to store new data ...

Comment: do you mean when it worked fast you just use SELECT 5000 istead of 500000? ) if this is one time operation maybe it has a sense to create non partitioned index, execute your select+insert and drop the index?

Comment: No ,even if select 100 it's taking around 17 minutes. No it's not one time operation , I have data flowing to the table all time , so I usually schedule it every 2 minutes. I'm still confused how I didn't face this issue before , knowing that I have the same setup now: all what I did is that I detached the database, copied it to external storage, formatted the server and the disks, installed SQL server, copied back the files to the disks , and attached the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 A.id
FROM  sys.partitions AS P
   CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1000 T1.id
          FROM dbo.table AS T1
          WHERE $PARTITION.PF1(T1.date) = P.partition_number 
           AND T1.id > @certain_id
           ORDER BY T1.id ) AS A
  WHERE P.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table')  
  AND P.index_id = INDEXPROPERTY( OBJECTID('dbo.table'), 'idx_c1', 'INDEXID')
    ORDER BY A.id;
```

from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2965553/decreased-performance-for-sql-server-when-you-run-a-top-max-or-min-agg

Comment: the table stores CDRs (call detail records) of a tier 1 voice carrier , so there is dozens of records every second. it's not efficient to select distinct date as there will be millions of distinct dates. In any way I tried the query and it's slow.

Comment: please add table definitions to the quesiton (I supposed date is a date, not datetime)

Comment: @user123 I modified the query to select TOP N rows from each partition directly but you need partitioned index on id

Comment: thank you!! I tried the query , and it's fast! but I'm worried about a thing , if the top 500000 are in two different partitions, will it be a problem ?

Comment: @user123 I think you need just to try it ) also it seems I forget to add the condition "id>@certain_id". I added it now and with this condition it should work faster

Comment: yes I already added it. it works like magic! thank you for this query , it's so helpful.

Comment: @user123 so now you can mark my answer as helpful one )

Comment: I tried but unfortunately I dont' have enough reputations to do so.

Comment: @user123 hm, I think you don't need reputation to accept the answer )